# How can I convert multiple textboxes in a Word document to tabular format?

Tags: microsoft-word, pdf, file-conversion

I have a PDF that was exported from Adobe Indesign file. I now need to have the contents of this PDF in Word but when I use Save As or use Export to, both options render the Word document with text in text boxes or autoshapes and they don't span across multiple pages properly. How can I fix this? I tried all possible solutions including these (https://answers.acrobatusers.com/Convert-PDF-Microsoft-Word-renders-textboxes-paragraphs-q122415.aspx) but nothing works. Help!

Comment: You will likely need to get the text from each box, pasted it into Word and then format it. What you want is not natively possible so far as I know.

Comment: Converted documents will ALWAYS have formatting anomalies that can make editing difficult. This is a byproduct of conversion from one  file format to another. Features in one program do not match those in the other.

Comment: There are various online services and downloadable application that attempt to convert from PDF (*Page* Description Format) to a flowable document, with varying degrees of success. The issue is that PDF stores an "image" of how the page should look, with hard line-breaks at the end of each line of text, in-line headers and footers, etc,, while document editors such as Word and Writer are designed to *flow* text, so that changing margin, font or paper size can freely rearrange words on the page.

Comment: There are currently no automated solutions for this. Expect to spend at least 10-15 min. fixing the layout on one page, maybe longer if the layout is complex.

Comment: When dealing with these kinds of anomalies, I often move info back and forth between Excel and Word.  Exporting your pdf to excel, may put your info into fields which can be grabbed as a table and easily converted to text in Word.